# Rank reputation not the same as profile reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation-history

This is a follow up from my previous question, where couldn't figure out why *30* points of reputation are missing. Now it gets more interesting as my rank reputations is *672*:

[image]

whereas the reputation displayed in my profile is:

[image]

as you can see on the top.

### Question:

Is this discrepancy related to some system synchronization that happens once in a while or a possible bug?

Comment: Likely caching. They probably don't update at the same time, just like meta rep.

Comment: [http://shouldiblamecaching.com/](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reputation leagues are only updated once a day, at 00:00 UTC (midnight) to be exact.